# ARM-GCC code directives for ArmV7A assembly code: .code vs .arm instruction mode directives

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, armv7

What is the difference between `.code32`, `.code 32`, and `.arm` directives in an assembly file?

The .S file will be compiled with `arm-none-eabi-as`

Are the three directives identical? None of these directives are explained in the programmer's guide (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0013/d/Introduction-to-Assembly-Language/Introduction-to-the-GNU-Assembler/Assembler-directives?lang=en), so it's hard to answer this myself.

Essentially, we wish to ensure that all functions writen in a given .S file are in ARM32 instruction mode (i.e. not Thumb).

--
Update: looks like I imagined `.code32`! The other two directives are identical, `.arm` is literally just shorthand for `.code 32`.

### Cheers for fast replies!

Comment: Refer to the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives).

Comment: Which says that `.arm` is the same as `.code 32` and `.code32` without space is not documented.  Indeed, my version of the gnu assembler complains that `Error: unknown pseudo-op: .code32`

Comment: On the contrary, `.code32` is a valid directive for x86, but not for ARM.  Perhaps you read something about x86 while researching this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are documented in the GNU assembler manual at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives.

> `.code [16|32]`
>
> This directive selects the instruction set being generated. The value 16 selects Thumb, with the value 32 selecting ARM.
>
> `.arm`
>
> This performs the same action as `.code 32`.

So either one would do what you want.

The `.code32` variant is not mentioned.  As you note, it doesn't actually work in GNU as.  It could be a typo, or maybe some versions have permissive syntax that makes the space optional.